# No sound through headphone jack (Dual boot setup)

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, sound, 20.04, headphones

I have dual boot setup (Windows and Ubuntu) on my Asus UX530UX laptop, last time I was on Windows I had my headphones pluged in and shut down the computer. Ever since, Ubuntu does not output sound through my headphones, however it does recognize the microphone input as the bar on the input panel is moving along with the sound (I haven't confirmed anymore than that).

I have tried the following:

- checked that the headphones are not muted from alsamixer
- restarted pulseaudio (multiple times)
- reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- today I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 hoping that it would fix the issue
- I even reset Windows but nothing worked

The headphones would work when live booting from a USB but not when it finishes the installation.

`pacmd list | grep "active port"` output:

```
active port: <analog-output-headphones>
active port: <analog-input-headset-mic>
```

`lspci | grep -i audio` output:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
```

`dpkg -l *alsa*` output:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                    Version              Architecture Description
+++-=======================-====================-============-=========================================
un  alsa                    <none>               <none>       (no description available)
ii  alsa-base               1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5 all          ALSA driver configuration files
un  alsa-oss                <none>               <none>       (no description available)
ii  alsa-topology-conf      1.2.2-1              all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf           1.2.2-1ubuntu0.1     all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils              1.2.2-1ubuntu1       amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
un  bluez-alsa              <none>               <none>       (no description available)
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64 1.16.2-4             amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
```

What should I do to make my headphones work?

Comment: I have same issue with Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score -1):

Updated with Official Ubuntu Docs on Wifi Powersave: https://core.docs.ubuntu.com/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/reference/snap-configuration/wifi-powersave

Comment: I dont think there is a /etc/default/tlp file in ubuntu 20, 'sudo gedit sudo gedit /etc/default/tlp' opened a new blank file in gedit